# Was the Israeli interception of a missile (from Yemen) recently "the first combat ever to take place in space", 62 miles high?

Tags: history, military, israel, space

[Claim](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/world-news/2023/11/04/how-israel-shot-down-ballistic-missile-in-space-houthis/#:%7E:text=Israel%20this%20week%20used%20its,to%20take%20place%20in%20space.) in *The Telegraph* on Nov 5:

> Israel this week used its Arrow missile-defence system to shoot down a ballistic missile outside of Earth’s atmosphere, in what is believed to be the first combat ever to take place in space. [...]
>
> The ballistic missile, which was fired on Monday, is said to have been a Qader missile – an improved version of the Iranian-designed Shahab 3.

Nothing more precise is said about the altitude of the intercept/hit, so what makes this "the first combat ever to take place in space"?

The *Daily Mail* [claims](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-12716503/Israel-space-war-Arrow-missile-defense-system.html) that intercept took place at 62 miles of altitude:

[image]

How verifiable is this? There are other, US etc. radars in the region that would have probably picked up something like this. So, has altitude of the intercept been confirmed by other nations own tracking system (I don't mean the press thereof)?

(FWTW, the DM claims the incoming missile was a "Barkan 3", but I no idea if that's just another name for "Qader".)

Comment: The [Kármán line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A1rm%C3%A1n_line) at 100km (62 miles) is *sometimes* considered to be the edge of space. If the diagram is correct, the missile would have been intercepted at the exact peak of its trajectory. But that would have been half way through its journey, a long way from Israel.

Comment: @WeatherVane: the graph may or may not be correct as to the [true height of the] apogee of the incoming missile, or the point of the interception along its trajectory. It's the Daily Mail, after all...

Comment: ...the distance between Yemen and Israel is ~ 2000 km and the operational range of the Arrow is up to 150 km. So the diagram itself does seem fanciful. But perhaps the trajectory is nothing like that, but gains elevation all the way to its target, before making a steep descent. However, 2000 km is the limit of the Shahab-3's range.

Comment: @WeatherVane FWTW http://www.astronautix.com/s/shahab3.html says the original Shahab-3 has an apogee of 150km, but a range of only 1200km, so this Qader/Barkan-3 must be quite an "upgrade".

Comment: @WeatherVane the Arrow 3 has a much greater range than what you are saying: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_3

Comment: I was looking at Wikipedia's [Shabab-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shahab-3) page, which also says the flight altitude is 400 km. I tried looking up the variants mentioned but they seem to be inferior. The [Arrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow_(missile_family)) also has 'exo-atmospheric' capability.

Comment: @DavePhD thanks. I linked my reference in the previous comment.

Comment: The page for the latter seems to be http://www.astronautix.com/g/ghadr1.html but the apogee info appears mostly the same so probably wrong.

Comment: https://www.militarytoday.com/missiles/qadr.htm gives an apogee of 200km, which seems more plausible.

Comment: The best other candidate for being "first" could be the 2022 UAE use of THAAD to intercept another Iranian-Houthi missile.

Comment: The *Daily Mail*'s blunder is that the missile it shows has, at 100 km elevation, *not* entered space :)

Comment: @DavePhD: yeah, the SM-3 Block II was apparently never fired in combat although it shot down satellites etc. in tests. That's a 21 inch missile as well, like the Arrow 3. The THAAD is a  tad smaller (15 inch) , but could in theory reach 150km altitude.

Comment: The Telegraph is behind a paywall and the Dail Mail just claims that the IDF said so. Is there a more reliable source that first this missile launch from Yemen aimed at Israel and second the Israeli shoot down actually happened? Maybe the actual official IDF statement?